# How to train a custom parameterized circuit with multiple parameters and intermediate measurements?

Tags: qiskit

[image]

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.circuit import *
from qiskit.visualization import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
from qiskit.quantum_info import *
from qiskit.circuit.library import *
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
QC = QuantumCircuit(10,4)
Qs = ParameterVector('a', 6)
for i in range(6):
    QC.h(i)
    QC.ry(Qs[i], i)

for i in range(9):
    QC.cx(i, i+1)
QC.barrier()
Ps = ParameterVector('b', 4)
for i in range(4):
    QC.h(i + 6)
    QC.ry(Ps[i], i + 6)
QC.measure(2,0)
QC.measure(8,1)
QC.barrier()
Qs = ParameterVector('c', 10)
for i in range(10):
    QC.h(i)
    QC.ry(Qs[i], i)
for i in range(9):
    QC.cx(i, i+1)
QC.barrier()
QC.measure(4,2)
QC.measure(6,1)

QC.draw('mpl')
```

Comment: similar question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/20718/software-tools-to-train-quantum-circuits-with-parameters

Comment: you should consider training the circuit separately, or use Pennylane will be a lot more easier than using qiskit. https://pennylane.ai/qml/demos_optimization.html

Comment: The puzzle is how to map classical data onto a Hamiltonian

Answer (score 1):

You can train it using a classical optimizer just as in quantum circuits without measurement. As long as you have an objective function, you can try using `scipy.optimize` or other classical optimizers.

Check out [this post](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/qaoa.html) for a good example. The example doesn't include measurement, but as long as you can feed a single number into the optimizer you're ready to start optimizing.

Comment: The puzzle is how to map classical data onto a Hamiltonian